# Show and hide items from one v-for select input based on the value from another using Vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have 2 select option fields using `v-for` loops from constants. One is for `sides` and another for `caps`. If a user selects `2-Sided` in the sides selection, I want the `active` item under caps to show false.

```
<template>
...
<!-- Sides -->
<div class="mt-6">
    <h3>Sides</h3>
    <RadioGroup v-model="sides" class="mt-2">
        <RadioGroupLabel class="sr-only"> Choose Sides </RadioGroupLabel>
        <div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-3 sm:grid-cols-4">
            <RadioGroupOption as="template" v-for="option in sideOptions" :key="option.name" :value="option" :disabled="!option.active" v-slot="{ active, checked }">
            <div :class="[option.active ? 'cursor-pointer focus:outline-none' : 'opacity-25 cursor-not-allowed', active ? 'ring-2 ring-offset-2 ring-indigo-500' : '', checked ? 'bg-indigo-600 border-transparent text-white hover:bg-indigo-700' : 'bg-white border-gray-200 text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50', 'border rounded-md py-3 px-3 flex items-center justify-center text-sm font-medium uppercase sm:flex-1']">
                <RadioGroupLabel as="span">
                {{ option.name }}
                </RadioGroupLabel>
            </div>
            </RadioGroupOption>
        </div>
    </RadioGroup>
</div>

<!-- Caps -->
<div class="mt-6">
    <h3>Caps</h3>
    <RadioGroup v-model="caps" class="mt-2">
        <RadioGroupLabel class="sr-only"> Choose Caps </RadioGroupLabel>
        <div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-3 sm:grid-cols-4">
            <RadioGroupOption as="template" v-for="option in capOptions" :key="option.name" :value="option" :disabled="!option.active" v-slot="{ active, checked }">
            <div :class="[option.active ? 'cursor-pointer focus:outline-none' : 'opacity-25 cursor-not-allowed', active ? 'ring-2 ring-offset-2 ring-indigo-500' : '', checked ? 'bg-indigo-600 border-transparent text-white hover:bg-indigo-700' : 'bg-white border-gray-200 text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50', 'border rounded-md py-3 px-3 flex items-center justify-center text-sm font-medium uppercase sm:flex-1']">
                <RadioGroupLabel as="span">
                {{ option.name }}
                </RadioGroupLabel>
            </div>
            </RadioGroupOption>
        </div>
    </RadioGroup>
</div>

</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
...
const capOptions = [
  { name: 'No Cap', active: true },
  { name: '2-Sided', active: true },
  { name: '3-Sided', active: true },
  { name: '4-Sided', active: true },
]

const sideOptions = [
  { name: '2-Sided', active: true },
  { name: '3-Sided', active: true },
  { name: '4-Sided', active: true },
]

const caps = ref(capOptions[0])
const sides = ref(sideOptions[0])
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind `update`/`select` event to the `sides` drop-down. In the event handler, based on the value chosen, you can loop through the caps array and set the `active` to true or false. I hope the names of capOptions and sideOptions are in sync

```
const capOptions = [
  { name: 'No Cap', active: true },
  { name: '2-Sided', active: true },
  { name: '3-Sided', active: true },
  { name: '4-Sided', active: true },
]

const sideOptions = [
 { name: '2-Sided', active: true },
 { name: '3-Sided', active: true },
 { name: '4-Sided', active: true },
]

onSideSelect(name) {
  const cap = capOptions.find(cap => 
   cap.name === name);
  cap.active = false;
}
```